# Help to buy ISA (UK) eligability

Tags: mortgage, isa, mortgage-qualification

We are currently saving for a mortgage deposit, I have already sent off my help to buy application as a first time buyer.

We are unsure as to whether my girlfriend is eligable. She previously had a mortgage under shared ownership and the flat was sold a while ago. Does this count as her previous investment in a property or does the mortgage being shared ownership have any sway?

We are aware that we can still use my isa to get a house together, more whether she is able to get her own help to buy isa (as they are per person) having only had a shared ownership mortgage before

Many thanks

Comment: I don't believe it to be duplication he is asking whether somebody who has never had any kind of mortgage can apply for the help to buy isa, i wanted clariication on whether or not a shared ownership mortgage discounts you from getting the isa

Comment: have a look at the link I provided in my answer to that other question, I linked to the declaration that would have to be signed. Your girlfriend could not sign that declaration, according to the info you have provided.